# php form that let's students check his/her mark after entering a correct ID number

Tags: php, forms, csv, html

I'm working on it now for a full day with no success. I'm just a beginner. I have a webpage for the course I'm teaching and I want to write a form that lets students check their mark after they enter their student number. I wrote the following form:

```
  <strong>Mid- term Grades:</strong>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
        <form action="Mark.php" method="post">
        Enter your 7-digit Student Number: <input name="SNumber" size="7"      type="text" /> <input type="submit" value="View Mark" /> <input type="reset" />&nbsp;</form>
```

and I put this form in my webpage that is written in html. Now, I want to check if the student number that is entered is in my class if yes show the mark if no say you are not in this section:

```
<?php

$SNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SNumber']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '$SNumber'";
$res = mysql_query($query, $connection);
if (mysql_num_rows($res) <= 0 ) $error = "You are not registered in this section.";
else{mysql_query(echo "$Mark")

?>
```

### My Questions:

1. If I put the validation command on the very top of my page for the course (as I read in internet) my page will die and become a blank page. What is the problem? How i can fix this?
2. I don't know how to store my information (student numbers and the corresponding marks) is it:

   ```
   SNumber=1234567 Mark= 122 | Snumber=1234577 Mark=3 | SNumber=1034567 Mark= 122
   ```

   Where to store my data how to store my data how to verify an input how to find and print the mark
3. Am I supposed to be good if I include the first form with post method in my course page. Adding verification command on the top of my course page (in my case it kills my page) and storing the information in the format I mentioned above in a php file called Mark.php? Nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be off in sort of the right direction.  Your HTML looks alright for your purposes.  There are 2 major things that you are not seeing in your approach (or at least you haven't mentioned them here).

1) The difference between server and client code.  The HTML file can run locally on you development machine, without a web server.  Your HTML file is specifying `Mark.php` as the page it will post to.  This php page will have to be hosted on some sort of web server, as it is a server-side page.  On your dev machine, you could install xampp, which includes the best web server, Apache, in an easy-to-configure GUI made for windows.  You'll have to ensure that the Apache module is started in the Xampp GUI, and place your files in `...pathToXampp/htdocs/containingFolder`.  Now when you post things to your php page, it will be able to respond.  You'll have to navigate in your browser to `localhost/containingFolder/nameOfHtmlFile.html`.

2) You have SQL database code in your php.  This means that you require a database.  You're in luck!  MySQL is included in Xampp.  Again, you'll have to ensure this module is started, then google for `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE TABLE` to see examples for how to set up your database.

Once you've started your server and database applications, you'll basically be running a web server off of your dev machine, which is your sandbox for the code you can later upload to your production server.

Comment: Thanks so much, it is very helpful. I downloaded Xampp for mac and I can see that everything there is unsecure as it doesn't allow me to set a password. Can I do anything about this?